# Linux Fedora - почему путь к файлам HTML -> CSS не верный?

Tags: html, css, fedora

Всем здравствуйте. Не так давно перешел с Виндовса на Федору 37. Был доволен, пока не взял в работу проект, разрабатывая уже на Линуксе. Ступор стал на верстке.

Пути указанные в html к стилям, скриптам, итд просто не верны. Для пробы создал простой html файл, рядом положил файл стилей css. Согласно правилам указал путь к даному файлу относительно index.html

А браузер говорит что нету такого файла…. ничего не пойму. Кто объяснить коротко в чем дело, что я делаю не так.

Comment: Вы же не просто файл открываете, а используете какой-то веб сервер?

Comment: Нет, для этого сервер не нужен (нус так было на Виндовс). Открываю файл html, но вместо этого вижу странный адрес file:///run/user/1000/doc/89aca1d1/index.html

Comment: Не пойму что за каталоги - 1000, 89aca1d1 (скажу сразу - каталоги названы латиницей)

Comment: Браузер изолирован от файлов во flatpak-контейнере

Comment: Без понятия...... что такое flatpak вроде знаю.... но что за контейнер и как защищать от него браузер я без понятия. Я вторую неделю на Линукс... и что то уже не знаю надолго ли.

Comment: Покажите html, покажите дерево файлов.